# How to inject dependency in constructor of model class in ASP.NET MVC 3 with Entity Framework 4.1?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, entity-framework-4.1

EF requires parameterless constructor but is it possible to override this some how?

```
public class MyModelClass
{
   ADependency _a;
   public MyModelClass(ADependency a)
   {
      _a = a;
   }
   ...
}
```

So when the client does a query like:

```
var myModelClasses = context.MyModelClasses;
```

each class gets created with the dependent instance injected.

Comment: Your class can have as many constructors as you want.

Comment: @Joe: yes but I need the dependency to get injected when the model object is created regardless of how it's created. I'll clarify the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the empty constructor and use the DependencyResolver and do it IN the constructor.

```
public class MyModelClass
{
   ADependency _a;
   public MyModelClass()
   {

            _a = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<_a>();
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: good suggestion, however I'm looking for a way to actually inject the dependency into the constructor.

Comment: @Christian this solution introduces another set of problems. Now you have hidden dependency with a singleton/static instance. Unit testing and refactoring will be difficult.

Comment: @Eranga, yes I realize this, but it's perhaps better than new up the dependency directly?

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible to override. EF have to use parameterless constructor and this behaviour cannot be changed because there is no way to use custom factories. You can either use the solution with service locator pattern mentioned by @Kevin or you can handle `ObjectMaterialized` event and set the dependency through the property of your entity.

Comment: thanks, I guess Kevin deserves the 'accepted answer' credit then.